# GtkDrawingArea не работает click в одном и том же месте

Tags: gui, gtk

У меня есть GtkDrawingArea и я прикрутил к ней key-press-event c помощью `gtk_widget_add_events()` и в `draw callback` с помощью `librsvg` я рисую svg файл и когда происходит клик (key-press-event) меняю изображение в буфере на другое (обновляю виджет - `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()`). Изображение меняется, но когда я много раз нажимаю на одно место (примерно), изображение не перерисовывается. Почему? Можно ли сделать какой-нибудь force redraw?